# Screen create/resume session, run command an detatch

Tags: gnu-screen

I am trying to make a startup script for my Minecraft severs but I can't figure out how to: 
If the session "Server1" exists, run a command in it, if it doesn't, create the session and then run the command.

I have read something about a `-dRR` switch but haven't been able to use it.

The script is `java -Xmx 128M spigot.jar -o true` BTW.

EDIT:
This is te command I've been using (can only run it once otherwise it will create news seesions)
`screen -dmS Server3 bash -c '/home/server/Minecraft/BungeeCord/Server3/start.sh; exec bash'` The start.sh file contains the above code.

Of course I tried to change the switch from `-dmS` to `-dRR`, but that didn't work.

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! this is not a free help desk. we're happy to help, of course, but please show what you have tried. for example, what `screen` command have you tried? what do you mean when you say you can't use the `-dRR` switch?